# For Loop with NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, for-loop

Just a quick question, when i do a for loop like this

```
for (NSDictionary *dic in myarray){
}
```

where in the array does it start, does it start from the last object, or from 0?

Thanks :D

Comment: Do you have an array of dictionaries or are you trying to iterate the items in a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it starts from 0. in case if you need further [clarifications](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/fast-enumeration-clarifications.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict;
for(NSInteger i=0; i<[array count]; i++){
    dict = [array objectForIndex:i];
    // your stuff here
}
```

Comment: The for loop in the question is known as "Fast-enumeration" introduced in Objective-C 2.0.  They both work and I would suggest to stick with the "Fast-enumeration" if you are comfortable with that code.